# Web Application Structure of Web Pages for Users

Tags: html, web-applications, web, architecture

I want to create a web application that takes a logged in user to their dashboard on log-in. What is the best way to structure the web app pages? Should I have a generic template page which auto populates with the logged in user details (object from db) for each user? Or should I have a seperate page (generated html page) for each user? Id expect the latter option to be extra storage on the db but the former solution would mean that there are more users hitting a single template. Or is there a better solution?

Comment: What architecture / language are you using? Depending on which, there might be plugins or gems that do this for you (such as `will_paginate` for Ruby on Rails).

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about your approach it's hard to give a specific answer to your question but here are some things to think about:

1. Your distinction between a 'general template that autopopulates' and a 'generated html page' isn't clear - if you want data to be coming from the database, yes, you'll have to run a query on that database to get the data for that user.
2. If you're showing the user a dashboard based on that user's data in your database then you would typically have an HTML page that your main language (Ruby on Rails, Python, PHP, whatever) inserts the right data into. That way each user's HTML page is generated dynamically for that user.

Comment: i'll be using lift with scala. The user will have a dashboard with data dynamically created. So would it be better to create a html page for each new user and have the information saved in a db? What im struggling with is how to save the information. I think it would be 1. save the user object, 2. create a html page for the user and save that on the box, 3 when the user logs in retrieve the html page and dynamically create the content base ont he user object

Comment: @Santiago - I'm not familiar with lift/scala, but if you're asking about keeping the data in a db vs. keeping it literally inside multiple copies of the same page, then DEFINITELY go with the database. Databases are designed specifically for this purpose and you don't want the redundancy and inconsistencies (and overhead) that will occur with multiple copies of the same page for each user. Generate your pages dynamically.